# Docker image failing to build on wsl

Tags: docker, dockerfile, wsl-2

I have the following image

```
FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook:python-3.9.12

ARG HADOOP_VERSION=3.3.1
ARG AWS_SDK_VERSION=1.11.901

USER root

RUN wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/${HADOOP_VERSION}/hadoop-aws-${HADOOP_VERSION}.jar" -P /usr/local/jars/ && \
    wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/${AWS_SDK_VERSION}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-${AWS_SDK_VERSION}.jar" -P /usr/local/jars/ && \
    wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar" -P /usr/local/jars/

RUN echo 'spark.driver.extraClassPath /usr/local/jars/*' >> "${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-defaults.conf" && \
    echo 'spark.serializer org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' >> "${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-defaults.conf" && \
    echo 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload True' >> "${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-defaults.conf" && \
    echo 'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem' >> "${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-defaults.conf"

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    pip install "jupyterlab>=3" "ipywidgets>=7.6"
```

When I try to build this image on WSL with "docker build ." I got the following error:

```
"The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/${HADOOP_VERSION}/hadoop-aws-${HADOOP_VERSION}.jar" -P /usr/local/jars/ && wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/${AWS_SDK_VERSION}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-${AWS_SDK_VERSION}.jar" -P /usr/local/jars/ && wget -q "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar" -P /usr/local/jars/' returned a non-zero code: 8"
```

When I build this image on Docker using Windows the build works ok! But when I run in WSL terminal I got this error. The image is the same on windows (Docker desktop) and WSL.

Why Am I getting this error since the image file is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in `ARG HADOOP_VERSION=3.3.1`, debugging I found a non Unix char in the line. I used `dos2unix` to parse the characters to Unix standard.